# Where are my .NDF files located?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a sample database called `TestDB`. After that, I ran this select:

```
select * from sys.master_files
```

I found my `.MDF`, `.LDF` files from this select. Then I want to find out the `.NDF` file location . Is it possible to see those files like `.NDF`, `.MDF` , `.LDF`?

Answer (score 2):

NDF is secondary data file, By default it will not be created unless we create the file while creating SQL server database or manually create it after database is created using AlTER DATABASE statement. SQL server by default will create one primary data file and one log file. If it is not visible in sys.master_files means you have not created it.

Read more about database files and filegroups

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189563.aspx

To add secondary data file please see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189253.aspx

Comment: Literally its not possible to open mdf,ldf file you can do it using notepad but it will contain all grabage value. You can attach mdf and ldf file to database using SP_Attach_db command:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx and then can use select statements to read data from table. You can also use *undocumeted* fn_dblog command to read contents of log file but this is not supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The ndf file is an additional file, which you can add to your database in the database properties. You have to think about files and filegroups as well. Otherwise you are not able to control, what is stored in which file. Multiple files can be used mainly to distribute load on your IO system, allow you to implement partial backup strategy for large databases etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174545(v=sql.80).aspx